# Code Runner does not run C# code

Tags: macos

While using the application [CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/) with C#, whenever I try to "run" the program it gives me this error:

`bash: Run Command: No such file or directory`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately. Just keep in mind that this site isn't about programming. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed [Mono](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) and added the configuration to CodeRunner to enable C# support?

I found a solution if you have installed Mono over at [MacRumors forums](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1328511) posted by user David Sheeks outlined below:

**Configure CodeRunner**

Open the CodeRunner Preferences dialog, go to the "Languages" tab, click the "+" icon and and specify "C#" as the Language name.

On the right you have fields where you can populate the language settings. Check the "Language uses compilation script" check box, enter `/usr/bin/mono $compiler` for the Run Command and set the File Extension to `cs`

Click the "Edit Script..." button and append the following to the compile.sh script (this will open in the CodeRunner editor):

```
file=$1
/usr/bin/mcs "$file"
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]
then
exit $status
fi
echo $file | sed -e "s/\.cs/.exe/"
exit 0
```

Mono installs it's compiler and runtime executable in /usr/bin and this is verified with the current version of the Mono SDK.

If you have done part of the above, and not setup the path's correctly, I would assume that the missing path it's complaining about is the fact that you either a) haven't installed Mono and the config can't find the compiler or b) youve installed Mono and the config in CodeRunner is invalid.

Comment: Note that due to the new updates in OS X 10.11 with system integrity protection (rootless), you will have to specify the path as `/usr/local/bin/mono $compiler` with the latest version of Mono (4.0.4 at the time of writing).